# PHP CLI vs MOD_PHP and FASTCGI

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos6

I asked my server support team to enable MOD_PHP or FASTCGI for me instead of CGI which is currently active. They told me they can active PHP CLI if I ask. AFAK CLI mean Commend Line Interface, so what they mean here?! I cant see how they want enable CLI in Apache?!

Can any one explain to me if I got it incorrect?!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it correct. CLI is command line interface (you can run php scripts from console).

mod_php, fastcgi a cgi (and a lot others) are webserver to php access techniques. CLI is a whole different thing.